# Measuring the precision of a clock

Tags: clock, precision

I have worked on a project using high precision clocks for some time now. I have yet to find a clear description on how manufacturers and scientist confirm and verify the precision of clocks like OCXOs.

My approach have been to use time and test two clocks relatively to each other. As time goes, the error between each clock will sum and create a bigger uncertainty.

But how is this done with cutting edge Atomic clocks within NIST standards ?

Comment: In the end, the most accurate clocks are assumed to be more precise because of the physics behind them (which are cross checked to work properly)

Comment: With precision oscillators (actually all references) I consider the 2 properties: **1)** absolute precision **2)** drift. I can have a clock which is 1 ppm (parts per million) accurate now but tomorrow it might have drifted away and have a 10 ppm error. Then I'd rather have a clock with a 100 ppm error but 1 ppm drift as I can compensate for that 1 ppm easily (just skip a count every 1 million ticks). An OCXO is a way to keep the **drift** low, the absolute accuracy is set by calibration (comparing to another clock which should be more accurate of course).

Answer (score 2):

As with anything that is adjustable, when comparing it and calibrating it against something else that is adjustable, how do you know what is "right"? What is considered "more accurate" if everything is just compared against something else that is compared against something else? There has to be *something* at the end of the chain where you say "This is exact". Some base value that all others are, ultimately, compared to.

And that is the Caesium atom.

I found a good [description of how they work](http://www.livescience.com/32660-how-does-an-atomic-clock-work.html) online:

> Inside a cesium atomic clock, cesium atoms are funneled down a tube where they pass through radio waves . If this frequency is just right 9,192,631,770 cycles per second then the cesium atoms "resonate" and change their energy state.
>
> A detector at the end of the tube keeps track of the number of cesium atoms reaching it that have changed their energy states. The more finely tuned the radio wave frequency is to 9,192,631,770 cycles per second, the more cesium atoms reach the detector.
>
> The detector feeds information back into the radio wave generator. It synchronizes the frequency of the radio waves with the peak number of cesium atoms striking it.

A good caesium clock has a precision of in the order of \$\frac{1}{3\times10^{15}}\$ which is far better than any crystal, OCXO, TCXO, or otherwise.

So having that as a baseline you can now calibrate other systems against it. And the further systems against those. The higher the accuracy of your nominal frequency you want the "closer" to that source you want to get.

But as has already been mentioned in the comments, that's only half the story. The whole purpose of OCXO or TCXO is not to make a crystal oscillate more closely to that precise "source" reference frequency, but to *keep* the it oscillating at a *fixed* frequency. A crystal's resonant frequency drifts and changes depending on temperature. By either controlling the temperature (OCXO) or compensating for the changes in temperature (TCXO) you can either reduce or negate that drift.

Very often it doesn't matter one jot if you are a few Hz out when dealing with MHz or GHz frequencies. What matters is that you *stay* that same few Hz out and don't drift. It doesn't matter (for instance) that everyone would have to tune their TV to 512.000038MHz (that's what "fine tune" is for), but people would get annoyed if they had to keep re-tuning between 511.999381MHz and 512.000482MHz all the time depending on the weather.

Comment: If the  frequency of 9,192,631,770 cycles per second has an error 1/(3E15), the deviation is 3.064 µHz only. If you compare two cesium clocks, the phase difference between them after 1000 s will be only 0.333 ps (picoseconds!) After more than 11 and a half days or 1 million seconds the phase difference will be 333 ps or 0.333 ns. A difference of 0.2 mm to the length of coaxial cables used for comparison will cause a time error of 1 ps only.

Comment: @Uwe Interesting. I remember seeing two cesium clocks used over the period of just 24 hours used to measure the difference in time caused by the gravitational difference of a few thousand feet of elevation between two places on Earth. They convert the counting to digital form, continually internally, which I suppose makes comparison easier but eliminates the ability to compare any residual phase difference less than one count.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a more accurate clock for reference, then it's always done by comparing clocks against each other.

You are comparing two clocks, but if they differ, how do you know which, if either, is right?

The answer is, you compare an ensemble of clocks with each other. Then you have to make the assumption that if *most* of them are keeping similar time, then 'time' is the average of the self-consistent group. Any clock that is running much faster or slower than the average is assumed to be faulty.

This is what is done with worldwide time, TAI. There are a large number (I have a figure of 40 in my mind, but it's from a long time ago and I can't verify it quickly, so it may be many more) of cesium clocks spread across the globe in standards laboratories. Time is compared between them, these days by GPS and optical fibre, but it used to be by point to point radio transmissions and moving portable clocks around the globe. When a new clock is built, it's compared with the ensemble, and after a lengthy burn-in and qualification period, if it's within the spread of the others, is brought into the ensemble. Similarly any clock in the ensemble that starts diverging from average too much is retired.